# Set column width using attribute (ComponentModel?) in class which I bind on DataGridView (C#, WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have DataGridView. I bind there a List. ObjectA have some properties. For example ID, Name and SortOrder.
I want to display columns in next order: SortOrder then Name.
I know if set

```
[Browsable(False)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

then this property will not appear in DataGridView as column.
I know that if I set

```
[DisplayName("N")]
public int SortOrder{ get; set; }
```

Where I can get all list of such attributes which I can use for DataGridView?

Comment: You cannot set the column width with binding.

Comment: Now in first column is Name data and in second - SortOrder. I want vice versa - SortOrder then Name. Is it possible to sort columns using classe's properties and don't touch DataGridView's columns. I don't want to find column with proper header and set index to this column.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `DisplayIndexAttribute` to use. You should create your own.

If needed I can add the code.

Comment: No man, thank you. I even won't bother myself to check the answer and mark your answer as correct ;-)